# Css dymanic width to a div with floats element

Tags: html, css

I need the parent div to be 300px at start, and every time user click a button, another div is insert to the parent, so i need him to dynamic grow. How can i do this?

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child"></div>
</div>

.parent {
     width:300px;
}

.child {
     width:280px;
     float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min-width` or just leave `width` at all.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="add">ADD</a>

<style>
.parent {
    width: 300px;
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden; /* clear after floating children elements */
}

.child {
    width: 280px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px; /* I set a height here just for this example, because children elems are empty with 0px height */
    background: green
}
</style>

<script>
$('#add').click(function(){
    var parent = $('.parent');

    parent.append('<div class="child"></div>');
    parent.css({width: (parent.width() + 300) + 'px'});

    return false;
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq9rw3o4/1/

Comment: for some reason the next div that i insert is going down, you have an idea why?

Comment: Parent's max width is 100%. If you want to make a parent div wider than 100%, you need to set its width by JS.

Comment: Only the first one that i adding is going down, the next divs is still inline, thats wired.

Comment: @user4207046: See this update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq9rw3o4/1/. It should do what you want now :-)

Answer (score 0):

simply use this for parent class styles.

```
.parent {
min-width:300px;
width:auto;

}
```

Comment: Why `min-width` and `width` together? And why you declare `height: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the css [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) property on the parent.

```
.parent {
 width:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your css

```css
.parent{ 
  min-width:300px; 
}
```